# Does unnest always display data in ascending order of hit number in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I have some data in Bigquery with the following columns

```
ID    StartTime    HitLevelData
```

My Question is if I want to select data in ascending order of StartTime I can write

```
Select * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY StartTime
```

But if I want to unnest HitLevel Data in my table and display in ascending order of hitnumber do I need to ORDER BY HITS.HITNUMBER

```
 Select ID, STARTTIME, HITS.HITNUMBER FROM MY_TABLE, UNNEST(HITS) HTIS ORDER BY STARTTIME, HITS.HITNUMBER
```

or I can just do

```
   Select ID, STARTTIME, HITS.HITNUMBER FROM MY_TABLE, UNNEST(HITS) HTIS ORDER BY STARTTIME
```

I am not sure if unnest by default always display data in ascending order of hitnumber or do I need to specifically write an order by clause for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe selecting from an array will return it in the order it is stored/written.  As for your two queries, it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  That being said, adding an `order by` statement is probably worth it if you are trying to implement some specific logic.

Answer (score 1):

UNNEST destroys the order of elements in the input ARRAY, use the ORDER BY clause to order the rows.

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays)

Also you can search for UNNEST [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) for more details.